# What does it means this command to run a perl web project?

Tags: git, perl

My boss let me on my own and gave me a command to run a project but I get errors and I would like to understand what the command means because maybe I execute it wrongly. It's a Perl project and uses [carton](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Carton-v1.0.12/).
The complete command is:

```
$ JSON_PRETTY=1 DBIC_TRACE=1 carton exec perl ./bin/single_fork_appkoki@denghi ~/projects/foo (git)-[wt_live] % ./bin/single_fork_app
```

I don't know if somethings has to be replaced. My questions are:

1. Should I replace `~/projects/foo` with something else? What does `~` mean?.
2. Should I replace `(git)-[wt_live]` with something else? More exactly `(git)`.

I think the question is complete, but if you feel I should give more info please let me know, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two commands in one line of code here.

```
                                           $ JSON_PRETTY=1 DBIC_TRACE=1 carton exec perl ./bin/single_fork_app
koki@denghi ~/projects/foo (git)-[wt_live] % ./bin/single_fork_app
  |  |      |                    |           |
  |  machine|                    |           command (executable)
  username  |                    git branch
            current working dir
```

Check this out. The `$` alone is a way show an example of a linux prompt where it is ont important what folder you are in or what your username is. The `JSON_PRETTY=1` and `DBIC_TRACE=1` set environment variables for this program run. It will run [carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Carton/script/carton) with the command `exec` and that will execute `perl ./bin/single_fork_app`.

It looks to me like this is the example for doing debugging, since `DBIC_TRACE` [turns on a trace in DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Troubleshooting.pod#Tracing-SQL) and `JSON_PRETTY` sounds like it would make output nicely readable instead of short.

The second line on the other hand has *user*@*server*, *current working directory* and the fact that there is a git checkout with the *branch name*. The `%` is the end of the prompt. `./bin/single_fork_app` runs the app.

Overall, those two are the same commands in my opinion (though that involves guesswork!). One for debugging/development and the other for production as a general example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will check what happens, thanks @simbabque